# Can't find my Staging Repository

Tags: maven, staging

I am a newbie trying to deploy artifacts to maven central for the first time. I followed the directions to configure maven to deploy to a staging repository. The maven build reports success. When I go to look for my staging repository, I don't see it. When I search for my artifact by searching for "markgrand" the artifact is found.

The group ID is com.markgrand, so I am expecting to see a staging repository with a names that begins with "commarkgrand-", but there is none. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's been awhile, so I do not remember the exact detail. The problem was that I had told the maven plugin to do too much. I think i had a step in there to close the thing, which made it no longer a candidate for deployment. Here is the staging plugin XML that is working for me:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.8</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
      <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```